# Laravel 5 Google chart Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-visualization, bar-chart

I`m new to the Laravel 5.4 and i need to implement Bar Chart for my web site.but it getting an error like this.

[image]

Here is my Config\App\Providers

```
ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
```

Here is my Config\App\aliases

```
 'Charts' =>ConsoleTVs\Charts\Charts::class,
```

In view Resources\Layouts\App.blade.php i added this.

```
 {!! Charts::assets() !!}
```

As well as in the relevant view

```
 {!! $chart->render() !!}
```

Here is my followed tutorial.

[enter link description here](http://laravel-news.com/laravel-charts)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?it is very important to me.
Thank you.

Comment: Did  you use composer to install it? Have you tried to run command `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Nerea No i did`t try such a thing.what is the command may i need to run?

Comment: open a console, navigate to your proyect and type `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Nerea .I run it and it says auto load is completed.but the error is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that you're using `version 2` of this package, as that's much older.

For version >= 3.0, your facade declaration should actually be:

```
'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts::class,
```